# Pre-compiled versions of often used scripts in browsers

Tags: javascript, browser, cdn

Does anyone know why browsers such as Chrome, FF and IE don't just have all famous scripts embedded in their install? They could have all the versions of jquery, for example, pre-compiled (i.e. in V8 for chrome) and the browser would just be able to recognize the reference to a cdn or simply a local script by the name of the script. And really, how much greater would that make the install of the browser if you included all version of, say, jquery, angular, dojo and ext? Compiled to C++ via V8 these scripts aren't very large at all.

Sure, you could say, 'but then it won't use the modifications I made in jquery-2.1.3.js'. True, but that's just horrible engineering.

It would be faster and save bandwidth.

But there is probably something I'm overlooking. There always tends to be.

Comment: On the same subject, let's talk about the universe...

Comment: jQuery 2.1.3 is 84kb. Unless you're connected to the Internet via carrier pigeons a local copy is not going to make any noticeable difference.

Comment: @Juhana A pigeon can carry Gigabytes, maybe even Terabytes. Size is not important because packet size can be enormous, it's latency :)

Comment: @Juhana, I disagree. Loading all of angular for example is always a big problem for web apps. I've seen apps that have included splash screens for the first page hit just for that.

Comment: Admit it, you are sitting drunk at home and try to lighten up your boring evening with this discussion.

Comment: @Someone, you found me out. No seriously. There is some stuff around the house that needs doing. And I'm in postpone mode.

Comment: AngularJS is 125kb. What they're struggling to load is the app itself, not the library.

Comment: @Juhana, that may be so, but parsing the whole framework even happens on a background thread to tackle these problems. Look at the problem RequireJs is solving.

Comment: There's nothing stopping the Gerben Browser™ from including this feature.

Comment: @nnnnnn GitHub: Gerben Browser repository. 1 contributor. *sigh* story of my life.

Answer (score 3):

Because there is already a whole protocol related to delivering resources to browsers and for caching them on client side and sending headers to tell the browsers when they should check for new versions.

Also, filename-1.2.3.js don't tell the whole story. There is also a build number after major, minor and patch. See http://semver.org/

You couldn't expect distinct browser vendors to take the responsibility to update their browsers every time any script was being updated or built. It'd simply slow down the delivery. Considering there already is a protocol for it. HTTP.

Comment: Note that I'm talking about major script here right? Are you saying that jquery-1.9.3 can have a different buildnumber than another version of 1.9.3? I've never heard of any major scripts that version that way. I think they always change the revision at least. Oh and I know the mechanism is in place, but why send it if it does not need to be sent?

Comment: I'm not saying. Semantic versioning is. And what you say about `bad engineering`, I call it `A person who's active on the open source community and is able to fix stuff in their own environment for the business need while he's waiting for his pull-request to get through`.

What I would like to see though, is a CDN in which I could simply opt into updates such as specifying script to be `filename-1.9.+.js` instead of hard coded 1.9.3.

Comment: Then he/she would definitely need to create an override called jquery-1.9.3.my-prototype-overrides.js or whatever instead of modifying the industry standard file and create madness for the next programmer that comes along. Nobody does that. Really.